# PHP: How to get a match value from a static Enum method?

Tags: php, enums, static

I would like to get a string value from a Enum static method:

```
<?php

enum Mensagem {
    
    case SUCESSO;
    case ATENCAO;
    case ERRO;
    
    public static function getCor(): string
    {
        return match(self)
        {
            self::SUCESSO => '#7FFFD4',   
            self::ATENCAO => '#FFFF00',   
            self::ERRO => '#DC143C'   
        };
    }
}

$mensagem = Mensagem::SUCESSO::getCor();

echo "<div style='background-color:{$mensagem}'> Sucesso ! </div>";
```

But I got this error:

> Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "self"

I tried `match(true)` but did not work too.

So, How can I get the match value from a static Enum method?

Comment: Try using the full enum name instead of self. So `Mensagem::SUCESSO`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a backed enumeration by adding directly to each case a value :

```
<?php
//            v------v------ Check this (could be int type)
enum Mensagem : string {
    case SUCESSO = '#7FFFD4';
    case ATENCAO = '#FFFF00';
    case ERRO = '#DC143C';
}

echo Mensagem::SUCESSO->value . PHP_EOL;
```

Output is `#7FFFD4`

Alternatively, if you want to avoid coupling the enum with some HTML color value, you can use an external function/method that would convert the enum to a defined value

```
enum Mensagem {
    case SUCESSO;
    case ATENCAO;
    case ERRO;
}

function GetEnumValue(Mensagem $enum)
{
    return match ($enum)
    {
        Mensagem::SUCESSO => '#7FFFD4',
        Mensagem::ATENCAO => '#FFFF00',
        Mensagem::ERRO => '#DC143C'
    };
}


echo GetEnumValue(Mensagem::ERRO) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output is `#DC143C`

[Try it yourself](https://onlinephp.io/c/b9f91)

Comment: So...Is It impossible using static?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, I'm not sure, tho. I gave you some simple alternatives to achieve your goals